# Authentication failed in Spring due to no mapping found for HTTP request with URI?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a web project using Spring Security. The user begin from login.jsp, pass through the authentication, and direct to hello.jsp. Take note that all JSP pages are locate in WEB-INF. During the process, I notice the URL begin with `localhost:8081/Project1/pages/login.jsp`, right after submit the page, the URL have change to  `http://localhost:8081/Project1/pages/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=792884C463EAC3C6CBC155EA75F4C6E4`.

And then the page showing me HTTP status 404 after the authentication instead of showing hello.jsp. In the console output, I see this message:

`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecurity3/pages/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringSecurity3'`

I am not sure what is miss configure in Spring configuration? The configuration code is as follow:

```
<http auto-config="true">
   <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/pages/hello.jsp" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
   <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
   <logout logout-success-url="/pages/login.jsp"/>
</http>
```

and my web.xml is as follow:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also you can refer to this tutorials: 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Answer (score 1):

Double-check if the security configuration is included in the main application context (as opposed to the servlet application context). The xml configuration file declaring the security filter chain (`<http ...>`) should be listed in the `contextConfigLocation` context parameter in `web.xml` (or be imported by one of the xml config files listed there).

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        ...
        [spring-security config file should be included here]
        ...
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```